# `npm install` fails with `ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir ...`

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

$ npm i inquirer qr-image
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path G:\My Drive\The Complete 2023 Web Development Bootcamp\Section 23 Node JS\2.4 QR Code Project\node_modules\ora\node_modules
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\The Complete 2023 Web Development Bootcamp\Section 23 Node JS\2.4 QR Code Project\node_modules\ora\node_modules'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\B420 AUROS PRO\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-15T17_04_15_591Z-debug-0.log

Hello,

Any npm package that I try to install has errors, and I can't find the issue.
I tried to force it nothing happened.

is there a basic configureation that I need to do?

In my knowledge NodeJs is installed correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: try shift-deleting `node_modules`

Comment: Is there `pnpm-lock.yaml`?

Comment: I deleted node_modules and tried again still showing error:
$ npm i qr-image
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path G:\My Drive\The Complete 2023 Web Development Bootcamp\Section 23 Node JS\2.4 QR Code Project\node_modules
npm ERR! errno -4052
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir 'G:\My Drive\The Complete 2023 Web Development Bootcamp\Section 23 Node JS\2.4 QR Code Project\node_modules'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\B420 AUROS PRO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-15T18_28_13_710Z-debug-0.log

Comment: I am still new to nodeJs so I don't know much about pnpm but I don't think there is.

Comment: Check if the path `G:\My Drive\The Complete 2023 Web Development Bootcamp\Section 23 Node JS\2.4 QR Code Project\node_modules` is a file, it says it's a file thus it errors

Comment: It is a folder because I created it using mkdir after the first error and also I tried changing the directory by putting the folder on the desktop Still giving me errors.